# Remove new line in wysiwyg redactor

Tags: php, wysiwyg, redactor.js

I'm using the wysiwyg in the back end and use the following code to limit the string, "...read more" will be displayed at the end of the sentence.

```
function limit_words($string)
{
    $word_limit = '60';
    $words = explode(" ",$string);
    return implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,$word_limit));
}

<?php echo limit_words($rows['content']); ?>... <a href="index.php">read more</a>
```

Here is my problem. The "...read more" is showing properly when the string characters are more than 60. 
[image]

But if the string characters are less than 60, the read more text is showing in new line. I know this is causing by `<p>`, which is auto generate from wysiwyg.

[image]

Is it possible to solve this issue on this section only?

Comment: you will need a custom regex to remove ether all html tags and trim or trim only the text in the html tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using regular expression to remove `<p>` tags around elements

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~</?p[^>]*>~', ' ', $rows['content']); 
echo limit_words($replaced); ?>... <a href="index.php">read more</a>
```